# DynamoDB Maps vs Lists for storing IoT Data

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, iot, aws-iot

I'm trying to store IoT Data from data loggers that can have a variety of sensors attached, below is an example. Each logger sends an MQTT message every 20 seconds

```
"state": {
    "reported": {
      "batv": 5105,
      "ts": 1614595073655,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    }
  }
```

My Question is in terms of storing these MQTT messages/readings efficiently in a DynamoDB table, should i store the readings in a Map containing Maps like this. (Note this is currently what I'm doing and when the number of readings gets large, it is very slow to load in AWS DynamoDB console.)

```
{
  "readings": {
    "ts1614592810955": {
      "battery_level": 5089,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    },
    "ts1614593692395": {
      "battery_level": 5093,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    }
  },
  "serial_number": "TDG_logger_thing"
}
```

The alternative which I'm leaning towards, is by storing readings in a list

```
{
  "readings": [
    {
      "batv": 5105,
      "ts": 1614594313407,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    },
     {
      "batv": 5105,
      "ts": 1614594313555,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    }
  ],
  "serial_number": "TDG_Logger_Thing"
}
```

Anyone with knowledge on DynamoDB or storing IoT data have any suggestions? greatly appreciated

(BTW The flow of data is)

**Data Logger -> AWS IoT -> AWS Lambda -> DynamoDB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a map or a list and split those readings and store them in separate items. With the same partition key like the device id, combined with a sort key for every reading, also including the timestamp. That way you can more easily query for all temp data and with the timestamp in the sort key you could use the query to fetch only the measurements from a specific period.

so primary key would be:
PK[device id] - SK[Measurement type - Data time] : (Attributes per measurement)

After that you can store whatever data you need for each individual measurement. and you can quickly update and retrieve individual measurements, hope it helps.

Comment: So instead of having an item for each logger, you're suggesting have an item for each reading?

Comment: Yes, don't be afraid of a lot of items in DynamoDB you can't get it to slow down. The main thing is to store it in such a way you can easily find it with queries later, queries are the fastest way after directly getting one item. It really pays of to have a good design before you start btw. I highly recommend the DynamoDB book by Alex DeBrie for some very good and practical advice on designing for dynamodb btw if you want to know a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

DDB `List` operations can be a limiting factor when you have use cases like trying to reliably modify attributes held in the List

**Example - List**

In a List, to set `temp to 30` where `ts = 1614594313407`, you would need to fetch the List from DDB, search / traverse each object until `ts = 1614594313407`, `set temp to 30`, then write the whole List back to DDB. Not quite transactional

```
[
    {
      "batv": 5105,
      "ts": 1614594313407,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    },
     {
      "batv": 5105,
      "ts": 1614594313555,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    }
  ]
```

**Example - Map**

With a Map, you can update the value of `temp to 30` where `ts = ts1614592810955` in a single update `"SET readings.#ts_id.temp = :temp_val"` reliably

```
{
  "readings": {
    "ts1614592810955": {
      "battery_level": 5089,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    },
    "ts1614593692395": {
      "battery_level": 5093,
      "temp": 20,
      "humidity": 50
    }
  },
  "serial_number": "TDG_logger_thing"
}
```